# Centering variables for multiple regression - interested in group effects

Tags: regression, centering

I'm trying to run a multiple regression model looking at the length-weight relationship in fish. So y = weight, x = weight. What I want to examine specifically is if the length-weight relationship between different populations (same species) differs - I've run the model as:

weight = length * population

BUT have also reading a lot about centering data in regression models. It seems to make no sense to me to grand-mean centre length for this analysis as i'm specifically interested in the differences in L-W relationship between the groups, but should I group-centre for length? Or, not centre at all?

Any help or pointers greatly apriciated.

Cheers.
G.

Comment: I suggest first making scatterplots of the raw data to verify if the relationships do in fact appear linear. I know that the von Bertalanffy growth equation relating fish age to length is not linear, so I suspect this relationship is also non-linear.

Comment: HI James, Thanks for the reply - I have also run the model with the logLength and logWeight but the centering still troubles me. Each group has very different range of weight (and length - which is highly interactive with population group) - so it seems to grand-mean centre the length variable across all groups would be silly. BUT VIF scores show population and length to be highly correlated...... can I ignore this if in fact what I am investigating IS that correlation between the population and the length/weight?

Comment: I would start with a simple case, two (very different) populations, and investigate the relationship - and then expand the study with additional population groups.